# selenium version + python

Tags: python, selenium, библиотеки

Пытаюсь сделать автотесты на selenium + python

на время прекратил эти попытки, и сейчас вернулся.

Попытался повторить простейшие тесты, а они не завелись.

1. Изменился синтаксис? (ничего не нашел у селениума). Переменная в блоке `try` больше не доступна в блоке `finally`.
2. selenium поддерживает только 88 версию хрома, когда у меня 90. Цитирую.
   selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 88
   Current browser version is 90.0.4430.85 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.ex

Подскажите, как вылечить это?
Selenium обновился до 3.141.0

Частично, проблема устранена, установкой дополнительной библиотеки wedrivermanager.
Также, скачал свежий webdriver, но не знаю, как заставить селениум искать его, а не мой хром.

Comment: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=90.0.4430.24/ скачать webdriver этой же версии ?) а как вы пытаетесь получить доступ к переменной которой не существует для finally? Если она находится в try тогда вынесите ее за пределы конструкции

Comment: @Rolles раньше, до обновления, она отлично оттуда бралась. Возможно глобальная область видимости(я к сожалению не в курсе).
А при скачивании отсюда(уже пытался ранее), просто запускается окошко из консоли и пишется, что webdriver(скаченной версии) запущен. И толку нет)

Comment: `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='to driver')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Изменился синтаксис?

Да, в Selenium 4 поменялся синтаксис. Рекомендую обновиться до последней версии.

Я рекомендую такие настройки проекта, чтобы всегда была актуальная версия Selenium и драйверов.

В `requirements.txt` указываем две библиотеки:

```
selenium
webdriver_manager
```

В консоли пишем `pip install -r requirements.txt`

`webdriver_manager` — это полезная библиотека, которая самостоятельно проверяет версию желаемого браузера и скачивает под него правильную версию драйвера. Затем кеширует. Если обновился браузер, то WebDriverManager сам скачает новую версию драйвера. Таким образом, версия драйвера и браузера всегда совпадают. Источник: [webdriver_manager](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager).

В папке пользователя создается кеш для всех нужных драйверов:

[image: Структура каталогов кеша для драйверов]

Далее в коде теста:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Подключаем менеджер драйвера Хрома
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 

# Здесь менеджер драйвера Хрома проверит версии и установит нужную.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

С такой схемой проблем не возникает с драйверами.